# Can we get visitor history on a Wordpress site?

Tags: wordpress, analytics

We've uploaded a Wordpress website. At the time I wasn't asked add a Google Analytics code.
Now I've added a Google Analytics account and added the code provided.

I just want to know if we can get visitor history before adding tracking code?

It has been a month since I've set up the site.

Comment: You could ask for a user's location and store some reference to that user in a database or something like that. You could also create some sort of guestbook that users add their name, or an email or any field you wish to have to identify them as a gateway to viewing certain content, although that is sometimes a poor UX.

Comment: No, you can't see before adding tracing code data

Comment: You cant add it to your analytics because that tracking code wasnt active, but in your cpanel you might have awstats or other visitor logs which you could view visitor data including ip, ip based location , timestamp etc.